# A literal string containing escape slashes on groovy

Tags: java, groovy

My groovy script calls other commands via vagrant. One of those commands is to echo some quotes on a file within docker.

The goal is, so that within the container, i want to have `BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"`. Now to do this on a bash script, i would need something like this:

`BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = \"1\"`

The issue manifests itself when i have to escape double quotations on the groovy as well.

If i call `vagrant("echo BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = \\\"1\\\" >> ${yoctoDir}/build/conf/local.conf"` on my groovy file, the outcome on the `local.conf` will be `BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS=1` (without quotes).

The correct way to do this would be to include an extra backslash on both sides (3 for the groovy, 1 for the bash script), however when i do that, groovy doesnt run and gives me syntax errors.

What would be the correct way to insert this literal string(`BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS=\"1\"`) on the groovy?

Comment: Just some insight i've gained while trying to fix this. I added 17 backslashes and i finally got one backslash into the `"vagrant ssh -c ${command}"`. This seems to matter on the shell that you use.

Answer (score 0):

In `groovy` you can do the following:

```
def my_var = /BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"/
echo my_var >> ${yoctoDir}/build/conf/local.conf
```